# Suppose a box contains 4 balls numbered 1,2,3,4. From this box, 2 balls are randomly drawn without replacements...

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose a box contains 4 balls numbered 1,2,3,4. From this box, 2 balls are randomly drawn without replacements. Let X denote the larger of the two numbers on the balls selected. Find the probablity distribution table of X and draw it's bar chart.

---

Distribution table of X:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline X & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline f(x) & 0  & 1/6 & 2/6 & 3/6 \\\hline\end{array}$$

And I'm thinking these are the only options for the selection we have:
$\{(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)\}$

I would appreciate any form of help. And if I messed something up please feel free to fix it or let me know!  I want to figure this out but with your help because I'm learning and I'm unsure.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that 1 must have probability 0.
The 6 possibilities you list are equally likely. There is only one with 2 as the maximum and so this has probability $\frac{1}{6}$. Over to you for the others!

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it, you can confirm if you'd like. :)

Comment: Spot on Taljana. For similar questions you may well find it helpful to use 2-D possibility tables.

Comment: Thanks! And sorry what is a 2-D possibility tables?

Comment: A table with the (i,j) cell of the table representing  i being the number of the first ball drawn (or whatever the question is about)  and j  being the number of the second ball drawn.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that $f(1)=0$. Whether or not you want to include it in the table is a matter of preference (and/or your teacher's preference). I suppose it cannot hurt to keep it there for clarity.

You have correctly listed the possible outcomes. Can you reason why they are equally likely? From here you can fill in the table by counting how many outcomes have larger ball being $x$, and divide by the total number of outcomes $6$. For example, there are two outcomes with $3$ as the larger ball, so $f(3) = 2/6$.

Comment: Alright with your help I was able to find the others. You check each possibility where the chosen value of x is the biggest. Can you confirm it is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

[image]

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure how to create that on here but I'll be writing/drawing it on a paper. Thank you!